# Dynamically generated html links work in Firefox but does not work in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I am trying to build an application to view YouTube videos based on categories. User is shown a dropdown of categories, he selects a category. A div 'rContent' is populated with a list of links in that category. When a user clicks on one of the links the YouTube video opens in an iframe. The problem is when a user clicks the link the video is shown in Firefox but does not work in Chrome. Nothing happens.

```
<!-- Dynamically retrieved list of videos shown here, see sample below -->
<div id="rContent"></div>             

<!-- YouTube video will be shown in this iframe-->
<div class="video-container">
    <iframe id="userVideo" src="" frameborder="0" width="560" height="315"></iframe>
</div>

<script>    
$("#rContent").on('click', '.vid_trigger', function() {
    var URL = $(this).attr('href'); 
    $(userVideo).attr('src',URL)
    return false;   
});
</script>

<!--- sample of dynamic content -->
<a class="vid_trigger" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/fgqpHl5OGFA?rel=&autoplay=1"> … </a><br></br>
<a class="vid_trigger" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/c-d4rDY70zk?rel=&autoplay=1"> … </a><br></br>
```

Comment: What is the variable `userVideo` set to?  If it is not set, you are missing quotes around it and a `#`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Line

```
$(userVideo).attr('src',URL)
```

Should be something like this:

```
$('#userVideo').attr('src', URL); //select using id selector
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried the preventDefault ? You should use preventDefault which is the default behaviour when you click the link.

Besides the links should not be inside the div #rContent ? You are using .on so the links should be inside the parent.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Dynamically retrieved list of videos shown here -->
<div id="rContent">
    <a class="vid_trigger" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/fgqpHl5OGFA?rel=&autoplay=1"> … </a><br></br>
    <a class="vid_trigger" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/c-d4rDY70zk?rel=&autoplay=1"> … </a><br></br>
</div>             

<!-- YouTube video will be shown in this iframe-->
<div class="video-container">
    <iframe id="userVideo" src="" frameborder="0" width="560" height="315"></iframe>
</div>

<!-- script must be placed after DOM elements -->
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $("#rContent").on('click', '.vid_trigger', function() {
        $('#userVideo').prop('src', this.href)
        return false;   
    });
</script>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bzppw/)